# Is it possible to create stacked bar charts in views?

Tags: charts

I'm using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module with hightcharts to create charts in views, but I'm unable to create stacked one's.

Is this possible in views? Or is there any way I can override it with a custom module to achieve the same result?

[Here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) is an example of what I need.

Also, my view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'stackedchart';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'StackedChart';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'My Stacked Chart';
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '50';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_bootstrap_table_plugin_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'field_x_qc_testset',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'field_x_qc_week' => 'field_x_qc_week',
  'field_x_qc_status' => 'field_x_qc_status',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'field_x_qc_week' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_x_qc_status' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['bootstrap_styles'] = array(
  'striped' => 0,
  'bordered' => 0,
  'hover' => 0,
  'condensed' => 0,
);
/* Field: Content: x_qc_week */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['id'] = 'field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['table'] = 'field_data_field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['field'] = 'field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['label'] = 'Week';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'xreport_qc' => 'xreport_qc',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['group_by'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'chart';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['library'] = 'highcharts';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['type'] = 'column';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['label_field'] = 'field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_fields'] = array(
  'field_x_qc_status' => 'field_x_qc_status',
  'field_x_qc_week' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['field_colors'] = array(
  'field_x_qc_week' => '#2f7ed8',
  'field_x_qc_status' => '#0d233a',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['data_labels'] = 'TRUE';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['tooltips'] = 'TRUE';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: x_qc_week */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['id'] = 'field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['table'] = 'field_data_field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['field'] = 'field_x_qc_week';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_week']['label'] = 'Week';
/* Field: Content: x_qc_status */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_status']['id'] = 'field_x_qc_status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_status']['table'] = 'field_data_field_x_qc_status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_status']['field'] = 'field_x_qc_status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_status']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_x_qc_status']['separator'] = ', ';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'xreport_qc' => 'xreport_qc',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'stackedchart';
```

If it can't be made with views, doing it with a custom module using EntityFieldQuery is also a good solution. My only issue is how to show the data in different x-axis values (field value) not knowing all the values of that field.

EDIT: Tried Pierre suggestion. dsm is outputing the name of the chart and I use it as $chart_id. No stack is produced in the chart.

The fields I have are `week` and `status`. I have multiple nodes, with different weeks and status and I need to stack the status for each week.
Below is the chart WITHOUT stacking.

[image]

Comment: Pierre, I solved the problem. I already had a view with multiple displays. Each one was filtered by x_qc_status (like different 'Joe'). I was assuming that, with the chart_alter function I was able to do it with only one views page. So I recreated this with multiple displays + chart_alter and now the chart shows as I need. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Refer to the issue about [Stacking column/bar charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364091) for an example of how you can do this with a custom module. Comment #3 in it contains a sample like so:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_chart_alter(&$chart, $chart_id) {
  dsm($chart_id); // Need Developer module enabled for dsm to work
  if ($chart_id == 'MYCHARTVIEW__DISPLAY') { // Watch out for those double underscores
    $chart['#stacking'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

This should work for both [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) as the charting library (engine).

## Option 2

Your `x_qc_status` is like the equivalent of "Joe" in the sample you referred to. But you don't have any equivalent of at least "John" (and maybe also "Jane")? In other words: I think you only have 1 dataset to be shown in your "stacked" bar chart, and that your problem is not in the chart, but in the related "view" for which you want to create a "stacked" chart.

Therefor try the "bonus tip" mentioned in [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://drupal.org/node/2426929). That may help to refine your view before actually creating the chart.

Comment: Pierre, that doesn't work. I already tried.

Comment: Can you enhance your question to explain the "that doesn't work"? That might help to get you going.

Comment: Sorry Pierre, it was not well explained. I edited and added more information. Hope it's enought to understand what's the issue. And thanks again for the support.